# Calculating the derivative of a function that comprises of two other functions, partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

The question is:

> Suppose $w=xy^2 +4x^2 - 5y$, and $x=g(t)$ and $y=h(t)$, where $g(0)=6$, $g'(0)=4$, $h(0)=-4$, and $h'(0)=-3$. Find $\frac{dw}{dt}$ at $t=0$.

What I have done is:
$$w = g'(t) h(t)^2 + 2 h'(t) g(t) + 8 g(t) - 5 h'(t)$$
and then I substituted in the values as provided by the question and I received 91 which is incorrect.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You did the derivative wrong. (And it's not $w$, it's $\frac{dw}{dt}$). Using implicit differentiation, you would have $w'(t) = (x)'y^2 + x(2yy') + 8xx' - 5y'$; you are missing lots of factors in what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(t)^2=2f(t)f'(t).$$

So, you need to check

$$w'(t) = g'(t) h(t)^2 + \color{red}{2 h'(t) g(t)} + \color{red}{8 g(t)} - 5 h'(t)$$